# How to change the value stored in name based on previous input from user in html?

Tags: python, html, django, database, if-statement

Good day. I am building a website using python django. I am trying to change a value in a table in the database containing student marks based on the student number(row) and assignment name(column). I have a function in views.py that uses if else statements to change the value which works fine as long the name="A1" is fixed to A1 (in the html code below) or fixed to any other assignment name but I have multiple assignment names ranging from A1 to A6. I would would like to change the value of name based on what assignment the user selects

the html code:

```
<h1>Fill in student assignment marks below</h1>
   <form action= "" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}  
      <input type="text" class="field"  placeholder="student ID" name="student">
            <label for="name">Choose an Assignment:</label>
                <select name="name" id="name">
                    <option value="A1">A1</option>
                    <option value="A2">A2</option>
                    <option value="A3">A3</option>
                    <option value="A4">A4</option>
                    <option value="A5">A5</option>
                    <option value="A6">A6</option>
                 </select>
      <input type="text" class="field"  placeholder="percentage" name="A1">
        <button type="submit" class="btn">save</button>
     </form>
```

The following is the view.py function to update the table:

```
def upload_A_marks(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        student = request.POST['student']
        name = request.POST['name']
        print(name)
        if name == 'A1':
            A1 = request.POST["A1"]
            new_Amark = MarksTable.objects.get(student=student)
            new_Amark.A1 = A1
            new_Amark.save()

        if name == 'A2':
            A2 = request.POST["A2"]
            new_Amark = MarksTable.objects.get(student=student)
            new_Amark.A2 = A2
            new_Amark.save()

        if name == 'A3':
            A3 = request.POST["A3"]
            new_Amark = MarksTable.objects.get(student=student)
            new_Amark.A3 = A3
            new_Amark.save()

        if name == 'A4':
            A4 = request.POST["A4"]
            new_Amark = MarksTable.objects.get(student=student)
            new_Amark.A4 = A4
            new_Amark.save()

        if name == 'A5':
            A5 = request.POST["A5"]
            new_Amark = MarksTable.objects.get(student=student)
            new_Amark.A5 = A5
            new_Amark.save()

        if name == 'A6':
            A6 = request.POST["A6"]
            new_Amark = MarksTable.objects.get(student=student)
            new_Amark.A6 = A6
            new_Amark.save()
   return render (request, "upload_A_marks.html")
```

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: try to get name as `name = request.POST.get('name')`

Comment: I tried this and the error still persists

Comment: could you show your model.